# Conflicting answers but Fubini's theorem should apply

Tags: real-analysis, integration

I saw the following problem while studying for qualifying exams. Let $N(x)$ be the positive integer which represents the decimal place in the decimal expansion for $x$ where the first zero occurs; so $N(0.0) = 1, N(0.1) = 2, N(4.121041) = 4$, etc. Calculate $\int_R y^{-N(x)}d\mu(x, y)$ where $\mu$ is the Lebesgue measure on the unit square $R = [0, 1] \times [0, 1]$.

The solution (I don't think the details are that important) given cleverly uses the Fubini-Tonelli theorem to fix $y$ and do the integral in $x$ first, involving a geometric series which can be evaluated in terms of $y$, and then integrates this expression in $y$ to get a finite answer.

Fubini's theorem clearly applies, as the integrand is nonnegative. My problem is that when I do the integral by integrating in $y$ first, I get infinity. For instance, $N(x) = 1$ on a set of measure $1/10$, and so we have 
$$
\int_R y^{-N(x)}\, d\mu \geq \int_{[0,1/10] \times [0, 1]} y^{-N(x)}\, d\mu = \int_0^{1/10}\int_0^1 y^{-1}\, dy\, dx.
$$
But $y^{-1}$ is not integrable at zero. So the integral should be infinite. But this conflicts with the answer given, and since Fubini's theorem applies, I should get the same answer with this method as the (finite) answer from the solution given.

Any help in explaining this discrepancy is appreciated!

**Edit:** After going through their solution more carefully, I believe the geometric series they derived is wrong, and that even when performing the integration in the opposite order, infinity is the correct answer. That being said, I'd still very much appreciate if anyone could check my above logic (in integrating in $y$ first).

Comment: Is $N$ well defined? $1=0.\bar{9}$, but $N(0.\bar{9}) \neq N(1.0)$, no?

Comment: Your proof is correct. If we integrate wrt $x$ first, then, denoting the $k$th digit of $x$ by $d_k$, we have
$$\operatorname{P}
 (d_1 \neq 0 \land \cdots \land d_{k - 1} \neq 0 \land d_k = 0) =
\frac 1 {10} \left( \frac 9 {10} \right)^{\! k - 1}, \\
\int_0^1 y^{-N(x)} dx =\sum_{k \geq 1}
 \frac 1 {10} \left( \frac 9 {10} \right)^{\! k - 1} y^{-k},$$
which converges only for $y > 9/10$.

Comment: @B.Swan, if there is more than one decimal expansion, the definition says to go with the one that ends with zero (rather than repeating). So $N(1) = N(1.0) = 0$. If a zero never appears in the decimal expansion (say, .1111...), then we set $N = \infty$.